# Спинер и ajax на сайте

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть задание: встроить спиннер с бутстрапа в код сайта. По замыслу, когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку появляется спинер, который несколько секунд крутится и после показывает информацию. Эту функцию я хочу вставить в код, где находится кнопка. Не очень понимаю, как его завершить.

```
function getCurrencies (coinName) {

    $(".collapse").append(`<div class="spinner-border" role="status"></div`)
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/",
        success: (coins) => {
          localStorage.setItem("allCoinsArray", JSON.stringify(coins));
          displayCoins(coins);
        },
        error: (err) => console.error(err),
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо в `success` удалить `div` с классом `spinner-border`

При ошибке тоже

Comment: Не очень понял. В success у нас же нет дива.

Comment: .........В смысле? надо из html удалить див ....а сделать это действие надо в методе success